# Annotating a corpus using Syntaxnet

Tags: corpus, annotate, syntaxnet

I am trying to annotate a corpus using Syntaxnet. I added the following lines in the end of the /models/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/models/parsey_mcparseface/context.pbtxt file:

```
input {
name: 'input_file'
record_format: 'english-text'
Part {
file_pattern: '/home/melvyn/text.txt'
}
}
output {
name: 'output_file'
record_format: 'english-text'
Part {
file_pattern: '/home/melvyn/text-tagged.txt'
}
}
```

When i run the command:

```
./demo.sh --input=input_file --output=output_file
```

I am getting:

```
./demo.sh: line 31: bazel-bin/syntaxnet/parser_eval: No such file or directory
./demo.sh: line 43: bazel-bin/syntaxnet/parser_eval: No such file or directory
./demo.sh: line 55: bazel-bin/syntaxnet/conll2tree: No such file or directory
```

According to the answer given ## here ## I changed my demo.sh file and now I get some errors which say:

```
[libprotobuf ERROR external/tf/google/protobuf/src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc:291] Error parsing text-format syntaxnet.TaskSpec: 200:8: Message type "syntaxnet.TaskOutput" has no field named "Part".
E external/tf/tensorflow/core/framework/op_segment.cc:53] Create kernel failed: Invalid argument: Could not parse task context at syntaxnet/models/parsey_mcparseface/context.pbtxt
E external/tf/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:333] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Could not parse task context at syntaxnet/models/parsey_mcparseface/context.pbtxt
[[Node: DocumentSource = DocumentSourcebatch_size=32, corpus_name="stdin-conll", task_context="syntaxnet/models/parsey_mcparseface/context.pbtxt", _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]]
```

What could be a possible solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it's not certain but I think you are not running the shell script from the root directory. Please try running it as per the instructions mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37496169/3929053)

I hope it helps.