# syntaxnet demo.sh hangs when i use text file input

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, syntaxnet

I am trying to use SyntaxNet's demo.sh to tag and parse my own file. Similar to the instructions on https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/syntaxnet , I added to the context file:

input {

```
name: 'my_input'
    record_format: 'english-text'
Part {
    file_pattern: './input.txt'
}
```

}

input {

```
name: 'my_output'
record_format: 'conll-sentence'
Part {
    file_pattern: './output.conll'
}
```

}

and then ran ./syntaxnet/demo.sh --input=my_input --output=my_output. However, the code hangs after getting the term frequencies. The issue is similar to https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/208

Answer (score 1):

I just saw that the top answer in the following thread provided the right command.
[Annotating a Corpus (Syntaxnet)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37464591/annotating-a-corpus-syntaxnet)

The instructions on the SyntaxNet page were ambiguous and made us believe that "--input=my_input --output=my_output" were only needed as changes to the command line input.